# Sum values on list sorted by Distinct C#

Tags: c#, html, sql, linq, list

I have a list in C# with this kind of data:

```
REST CENA 5
REST COMIDAS 3
REST DESAYUNO 4
VIPP CENA 52
VIPP COMIDAS 31
VIPP DESAYUNO 45
REST CENA 2
REST COMIDAS 8
REST DESAYUNO 87
VIPP CENA 12
VIPP COMIDAS 325
VIPP DESAYUNO 21
```

and I would like to be able to display on an input in HTML the sum of all the data for REST, VIPP, COMIDAS, DESAYUNOS and CENA, like this

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(l => l.Pdv).Distinct())
<input value="@item">

                                                    }
                                                   @*
```

But this only give me the values of REST and VIPP witch is fine but i would like to also sum al values of REST and VIPP like this

```
REST 109
VIPP 486
```

and also be able to get

```
CENA 71
COMIDAS 367
DESAYUNO 293
```

I know I need 6 separate queries but how can I write those?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a `GroupBy`

```
foreach(var item in Model.GroupBy(l => l.Pdv)
                         .Select(g => new 
                                      {
                                          Pdv = g.Key, 
                                          Sum = g.Sum(l => l.WhateverYouAreSumming) 
                                       }))
```

Comment: and i also have a quantity item on my list is there a way to multiply the quantity to the number and then sum all totals for distinc? like this:
foreach(var item in Model.GroupBy(l => l.Pdv)
                         .Select(g => new 
                                      {
                                          Pdv = g.Key, 
                                          Sum = g.Sum(l => l.WhateverYouAreSumming*quantityItem) 
                                       }))

Comment: @ArturoMartinez Sure though It should looks something like `g.Sum(l => l.Amount * l.Quantity)`